# INSERT on Oracle with error in AdonisJS. What is the right way to do this?

Tags: oracle, adonis.js

When attempting to insert into Oracle using the Adonis Database, an error is generated for all fields of type string.

I am using AdonisJS 4.1 and Oracle 11.

JSON Submitted:

```
{
"codepi": "1",
"codoem": "5",
"datcer": "01/01/2007",
"cerapr": "2586",
"unimed": "Size",
"medepi": "P",
"desepi": "Ear Protector 01"
}
```

Code in Controller:

```
'use strict'

const Database = use ('Database')

class EstoqueEpiController {
  async store ({response, request}) {
    const data = request.only ([
      'codepi',
      'codoem',
      datcer,
      'cerapr',
      'unimed',
      'medepi',
      'desepi',
    ])

    response = await Database.connection ('oracle')
      .table ('USU_T096EPI')
      .insert ({
        USU_CodEpi: data.codepi,
        USU_CodOem: date.codoem,
        USU_DatCer: data.datcer,
        USU_CerApr: data.cerapr,
        USU_UniMed: data.unimed,
        USU_MedEpi: data.medepi,
        USU_DesEpi: data.desepi,
      })

    Database.close ()

    return response

  }
}

module.exports = EpiController
```

Error returned:

> "message": "insert into \" USU_T096EPI \ "(\" USU_CerApr \ ", \" USU_CodEpi \ ", \" USU_CodOem \ ", \" USU_DatCer \ ", \" USU_DesEpi \ ", \" USU_MedEpi \ ", \ "USU_UniMed \") values ​​(: 1,: 2,: 3,: 4,: 5,: 6,: 7) - ORA-00904: \ "USU_UniMed \": invalid identifier "

Comment: Can you post the table definition (output of DESCRIBE USU_T096EPI)

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00904 [oracle documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php) :

*You tried to execute a SQL statement that included an invalid column name or the column name is missing. This commonly occurs when you reference an invalid alias in a SELECT statement.*

Check the column names

&

I don't know if it has an impact (line 4) :

```
const data = request.only ([
      'codepi',
      'codoem',
      datcer, < 'datcer'
      'cerapr',
      'unimed',
      'medepi',
      'desepi',
    ])
```